# Read TextBox in another class

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

So I have written a program that connects to a DB and everything works great. However, I want to add a button when pressed will popup another form with the tables and columns of the DB it is connected to. I have done this in the pass with reading from a file path and pulling up the folders and things inside but for some reason I cannot replicate it.

When I did it in the past I had to create a new form and obviously the form.cs but then I had to create another class to do the parsing. I figured I would have to do the same with creating a class that would execute the sql query and then display it in my list boxes inside the form.cs. However, the one issue I am running into is reading the connection string from my form1.cs so I can run the query using that connection string. Any help/ guidance would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind I am fairly new to C# and using sql statements within it.

Here is the little code I have now

Button Click in my form1.cs

```
 private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Fun = new DBTableColSearch();

            var DBLocation = Fun.searchMyDataBase();

        }
```

Separate class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLTool
{
    public class DBTableColSearch
    {


        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string ColName { get; set; }
        public static SqlConnection myConnection = null; 




        public string searchMyDataBase()


          {
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text))   
            }
something.ShowDialog();

            return something.userDBLocations;

            }
    }
}
```

Form.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLTool
{
    public partial class DBSearch : Form
    {
        private DBTableColSearch[] _DBLocations;
        public string userDBlocation;

        public DBSearch(DBTableColSearch[] DBLocations)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _DBLocations = DBLocations;
            TableLB.Items.AddRange(_DBLocations.Select(x => x.TableName).Distinct().ToArray());
        }

        private void TableLB_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColumnLB.Items.Clear();
            ColumnLB.Items.AddRange(_DBLocations.Where(x => x.TableName == TableLB.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you stuck? Your DB and connection is great but when you press the Button, what is the issue now? Also where is the TextBox declared, in which class? How about your Button?

Comment: @Ian Well in my public class DBTableColSearch the public string searchMyDataBase() says not all code paths return a value. I haven't even connected the Btn_Click to anything yet just because it won't run anyways. Furthermore, if you hover over DBConnectionBox.Text is says "The name DBConnectionBox does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Ian I have made some edits to what was originally on there to somewhat match my previous code for another program that pops a new window up on button click like I am wanting here.

Comment: Does your: searchMyDataBase code correct? It seems like there are couple of issues at once in your code... Perhaps you want to ask the question one by one or try to solve them first before you ask one which really troubles you? Otherwise, it is also pretty hard for the community to look and to give answers to multiple problems at the same time.

Comment: No it doesn't work. My first problem would be passing the connection string from my form1.cs into my separate class.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand is that you have a problem with passing your connection string value from one class (form) to another...

A part of good practice is defining string values that might be changed later in your application is placing it on the configuration file. (Makes things easy to manage)

On your App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myCon" value="the connection string"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I defined a key named "myCon" with value "the connection string"
So in your application you can access myCon like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myCon"];
```

If there's a warning saying it's obsolete just use this instead:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myCon"];
```

Take note that this uses the System.Configuration namespace so add it to your using statements.

The benefit of this is that you don't have to change the entire code in-case your connection string should be updated and it is accessible almost anywhere on your project.

UPDATE:

Since you mentioned getting the connection string value from user input, you can pass objects to other class in several ways...

1) Using constructors (You can pass any object even if it is a type of SqlConnection):

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private string _connection;

    public Form2(string connection)
    {
       _connection = connection; 
    }
}
```

On Form1 btn click event:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(DBLocation); // var DBLocation = Fun.searchMyDataBase();
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

2) Public properties

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public string _connection { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
    }
}
```

On Form1 btn click event:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); 
var DBLocation = Fun.searchMyDataBase();
frm2._connection = DBLocation;
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

There are other ways too but this examples should be enough.

Comment: That would be correct in passing it from the form to another class. So the value "the connection string" I am guessing you would put what it is between the "". However, I am allowing the connection string to be changed via a textbox, so I can connect to any database as long as I have the connection string. How would I go about doing that then?

Comment: Could I do <add key="myCon" value="DBConnectionBox.Text"/>? And then  put

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("myCon")) ;
            {
                var ManualCmd = new SqlCommand();
            }

Comment: No, the value in the app settings is read as is. meaning if you did it like that it will be "DBConnectionBox.Text". I updated my answer on how to pass values from one form to another. Try it out.

Comment: John, so this way I wouldn't even need my extra class would I?

Comment: Also when you put DBLocation do you mean DBConnectionBox.Text? Or where are you getting the DBLocation from?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton if the connection string is the only reason for that class' existence then you may remove it. What I showed you is that as long as you have the value for your connection string in Form1, you can pass it to other forms using the methods above

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton DBLocation  refers to where you get the location from. If DBConnectionBox.Text is in Form1 then simply use that value.

Comment: Awesome! So when I click that button it pops up a blank dialog box. Now just time to write the SQL query in my form.cs and populate the ListBox. Any words of wisdom on how to go about doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102653/discussion-between-john-ephraim-tugado-and-james-robert-singleton).